# FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory - SPFX Solutionn Terminal error

Tags: javascript, spfx, spfx-webparts, solution, gulp

When I try to run `gulp serve` command in the terminal, it works sometimes, but sometimes it throws some error like this, which I mentioned in the image below.

[image]

And it takes more time to run, so can someone explain to me in detail, what that problem is.

How can we get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to increase the memory dedicated to gulp. Try this command:

```
gulp serve --nobrowser --max_old_space_size=4000
```

Comment: I tried this command, and after this, nothing happened like what was in my questions, it was beneficial for me, Thank you